# Threading in CLR in SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, multithreading, sql-server-2008, clr

I have a `CLR` process which runs under `SQL Server2008`. It builds a cache of several tables data to hold in a static class for use later by other calls.

My question is could I improve the process of loading this cache by spawning threads to load each data set/ table in my cache?

I've steared clear of this in the past as various posts have suggested leave the thread management to `SQL Server`. However I could really do with speeding up this process.
Currently its a sequential process to load each data set. If I could run these concurrently it would be very handy. A process I've done many atime outside of the `CLR` cover to get some extra performance gains.

Any ideas help tips very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use threads, but they must behave. Otherwise you'll lose the benefits of using them.

From [the CLR Host Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131047.aspx)

**How SQL Server and the CLR Work Together**

> This section discusses how SQL Server integrates the threading,
>   scheduling, synchronization, and memory management models of SQL
>   Server and the CLR. In particular, this section examines the
>   integration in light of scalability, reliability, and security goals.
>   SQL Server essentially acts as the operating system for the CLR when
>   it is hosted inside SQL Server. The CLR calls low-level routines
>   implemented by SQL Server for threading, scheduling, synchronization,
>   and memory management. These are the same primitives that the rest of
>   the SQL Server engine uses. This approach provides several
>   scalability, reliability, and security benefits.
>
> Scalability: Common threading, scheduling, and synchronization
>
> CLR calls SQL Server APIs for creating threads, both for running user
>   code and for its own internal use. In order to synchronize between
>   multiple threads, the CLR calls SQL Server synchronization objects.
>   This allows the SQL Server scheduler to schedule other tasks when a
>   thread is waiting on a synchronization object. For example, when the
>   CLR initiates garbage collection, all of its threads wait for garbage
>   collection to finish. Because the CLR threads and the synchronization
>   objects they are waiting on are known to the SQL Server scheduler, SQL
>   Server can schedule threads that are running other database tasks not
>   involving the CLR. This also enables SQL Server to detect deadlocks
>   that involve locks taken by CLR synchronization objects and employ
>   traditional techniques for deadlock removal.
>
> Managed code runs preemptively in SQL Server. The SQL Server scheduler
>   has the ability to detect and stop threads that have not yielded for a
>   significant amount of time. The ability to hook CLR threads to SQL
>   Server threads implies that the SQL Server scheduler can identify
>   "runaway" threads in the CLR and manage their priority. Such runaway
>   threads are suspended and put back in the queue. Threads that are
>   repeatedly identified as runaway threads are not allowed to run for a
>   given period of time so that other executing workers can run.

Answer (score 0):

Static data shared across invocations - not a good plan for CLR calls:
[SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/clr-integration-architecture-clr-hosted-environment?view=sql-server-2017)

> **Programming Model Restrictions**
>
> The programming model for managed code
>   in SQL Server involves writing functions, procedures, and types which
>   typically do not require the use of state held across multiple
>   invocations or the sharing of state across multiple user sessions.
>   Further, as described earlier, ***the presence of shared state can cause
>   critical exceptions that impact the scalability and the reliability of
>   the application***.
>
> Given these considerations, we discourage the use of static variables
>   and static data members of classes used in SQL Server. For SAFE and
>   EXTERNAL_ACCESS assemblies, SQL Server examines the metadata of the
>   assembly at CREATE ASSEMBLY time and fails the creation of such
>   assemblies if it finds the use of static data members and variables.